# Hide or show SSRS component based on multivalue parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that is based on a parameter that can have multiple values. For example: `'0','1'` and `'0','2'` (like an IN statement).

Now, I have to show certain parts in the the report whenever the parameter is 0 AND 1, and hide certain parts in the report whenever the parameter is 0 AND 2.

But… This 0 value is always the issue here. I know I have to use the visibility expression for this, but I cannot seem to write the correct expression.

So, when my parameter (Parametername = Prognosis) is `(0 and 1)`, I need the component to show. When my parameter is `(0 and 2)`, I need the component to hide. By the way, it is never just '0', or just '1', or just '2'.

I tried this, but no success:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Prognosis.Value(0) = 0 and Parameters!Prognosis.Value(0) = 1,False,IIF(Parameters!Prognosis.Value(0) = 0 and Parameters!Prognosis.Value(0) = 2,True,False))
```

Could someone help me with writing this expression?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join()` to put the values of the parameter into a string. So it would be..

```
=join(Parameters!Thingy.Value, ",")
```

Then you can see what values are returned by the string. e.g.

```
=iif(join(Parameters!Thingy.Value, ",") = "0,1", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Sounds logical. Thanks. I am however getting the error "The visibility.Hidden expression for the rectangle6 contains an error: [BC30108] Parameter is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: Apologies, it's "Parameters" not Parameter. I'll edit my answer.